# Laravel 5.1 - Setting X-Frame-Options Causes Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I added the following middleware to the HTTP Kernel stack, in app/Http/Kernal.php, which adds the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN to the header.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FrameGuard
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It causes a none-related error to show and part of the view is also rendered. This part of the view is rendering a list from the database, which works when the FrameGuard middleware is removed from the stack.

```
FatalErrorException in
MySqlGrammar.php line 139:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

[image]

This is the middleware stack in app/Http/Kernel.php.

```
protected $middleware = [
    CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    StartSession::class,
    ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    Middleware\AccessControlAllowOrigin::class,
    FrameGuard::class,
];
```

When `FrameGuard::class` is removed, everything works as expected, however when `FrameGuard::class` is added it causes the above error. Further more, when I keep `FrameGuard::class` in the stack and comment out `$request->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');` inside of the `FrameGuard` middleware class, I get the same error.

Has anyone else ran into something similar or am I going about adding this header in an incorrect way?

Comment: That's weird, however I wanna know why you didn't do name-spacing on it `\App\Http\Middleware\FrameGuard::class` ?

Comment: @revo There is no need to namespace `FrameGuard::class` since `Kernel.php` is already inside the `\App\Http\Middleware` namespace.

Comment: `Kernel.php` namespace is `App\Http` and not `\App\Http\Middleware` by default

Comment: How is a MySqlGrammar error at all related to an HTTP response header? Can you show more of the stack trace?